# How to set the vice versa condition for django models

Tags: python, django

I am using `Django3` and `model`

I want to get the data of `Distance` from one city to another city.

But in the database, only the distance A to B is stored ( because distance of B to C is the same)

So, what I want to is fetch the correct row, regardless the order of cities.

I can do this with use these two sentences and error check each.

```
Distance.objects.get(key_first=firstcity, key_second=secondcity)

Distance.objects.get(key_second=secondcity, key_second=firstcity)
```

However it looks a bit awkward and it requres two times DB fetch, Is there any smarter way like this below??

```
Distance.objects.get((key_first=firstcity, key_second=secondcity) | (key_second=secondcity, key_second=firstcity))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost hit it with the second example:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Distance.objects.filter(Q(key_first=firstcity, key_second=secondcity) | Q(key_second=secondcity, key_second=firstcity)).first()
```

[Docs on Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

Comment: WOW `Q` is quite nice for my purpose. thank you very much